# Adoption rate of Phone Verification in Sign Up form?

Tags: registration, verification

Of late we could see Phone Verification method is used in account registration forms so as to prove one is not a robot (e.g., Google signup form). So how popular is it's adoption rate? And how much it has increased the user's confidence to submit their own number.

Answer (score 1):

Phone verification should not be used to prove that you are not a robot, but to prove that you are you, and to ensure that would be hackers need more than just a user name / password to get in.

Phone verification just to prove that I am not a robot would be a huge deterrent for me to even register at a site. As it would for sites that hold information me that **I** do not consider "sensitive".

Also note that that the two-step verification process for Google accounts is an **optional** extra security measure.